# Cisco IOS command to show only interfaces in the same format as show run

Tags: command, cisco, cisco-ios

What is the command to only show interface details in the same format as 'Show run'?

The other commands, `show int brief` etc. show the interfaces in a different format but I want the same format as when running 'show run'. I think there is a specific command for this and not a filtered existing command,

e.g., I would like the output like this:

```
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1/11
 description Uplink to xxxx
 switchport
 switchport trunk native vlan 2000
 switchport trunk allowed vlan xxxxxxx
 switchport mode trunk
 switchport nonegotiate
 ip arp inspection trust
 ip dhcp snooping trust
```

Comment: You are better off asking this on https://serverfault.com/ Since StackOverlfow is programming questions. Also the `iOS` tag is for the Apple iOS operating system, not Cisco router OS.

Answer (score 1):

i think you're looking for

```
show run int te1/1/11
```

if you want all the interfaces it would be something like

```
show run | b TenGigabitEthernet
```

changing "TenGigabitEthernet" to the first device. "Ethernet" might just work on most devices natively.

Now that i think about it, the following might work

```
show run int range te 1/1/1-12
```

this should show tenGigabitEthernet 1/1/1 through 1/1/12 but i can't remember if range works on show run int.

One final option is section searching

```
Show run | s TenGigabitEthernet
```

if the switch handles the section search/filter function (some don't), it should show all sections with TenGigabitEthernet in the title

Answer (score 1):

show run int te1/1/11

This was exactly what i was looking for!

(although i understand i was on the wrong site!)

cheers!
Jon